# Why is my program showing a TypeError?

Tags: python, python-3.4

Every time I run my code I get this error

```
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found
```

The error shows up even when I have converted each element in the list to a string. Please help me fix this. The code is

```
  def add_list(list1):
    m=0
    for x in list1:
      m=m+x
    return m

  def summarize(list2):
    list1 = list2
    for x in list2:
      x = "{}".format(x)
    return "The sum of {} is {}.".format("".join(list2), add_list(list1))

  summarize([1,2,3])
```

Comment: You are operating under false assumptions because you didn't actually modify your list at all.

Comment: Try to `"".join([1,2,3])`.  What happens?  How about `"+".join(map(str,[1,2,3]))`?

Comment: `str.join` takes a sequence of `str`.

Comment: @Shashank But I am modifying the list in the statement x = "{}".format(x)

Comment: @RameshSingh Are you? Print the list before and after the loop. `x` is just an *alias* that is iteratively assigned to the value of each element in the list. When you do an assignment to that alias, you are only changing what the name refers to, not what the list element actually is. To do that you would have to do something like `mylist[0] = str(mylist[0])`

Comment: The most Pythonic way of turning a list of integers into its corresponding list of strings is the following list comprehension: `mylist = [str(x) for x in mylist]` Another way is `mylist = map(str, mylist)`. Another way (which is more akin to classical procedural programming languages) is `for i, item in enumerate(mylist): mylist[i] = str(item)`

Answer (score 1):

When you run a for loop over a list of immutable objects like strings or numbers it's actually making what's effectively a copy. It doesn't take the actual element itself out of the list. So that means

```
for x in list2:
  x = "{}".format(x)
```

Changes nothing, because what happens could be written verbosely like this:

```
for x in list2:
  >>> x = list[0]
  x = "{}".format(x)
  >>> x = list[1]
  x = "{}".format(x)
  >>> x = list[2]
  x = "{}".format(x)
```

You constantly change x, but that doesn't do anything to the elements of the list. If you want to loop over the elements of a list you need to do this

```
for i,x in enumerate(list2):
  list[i] = "{}".format(x)
```

In that format, 'i' will be set to the index of the element that x currently is so you can refer back to the actual position in the list and edit it there, which WILL result in the list itself changing.

Also you can just use str(x) to turn something into a string, it's much cleaner. It also works on any datatype so you can always print something

```
>>> str([12,1,"abba"])
"[12,1,'abba']"
>>> str(open("I'm a file.txt",'r'))
"<open file 'I'm a file.txt', mode 'r' at 0x0000000002ADC420>"
>>> str(None)
"None"
```

However I recommend trying some of the other solutions for how to print this, this isn't ideal. I just thought it was valuable for you to understand the error.

Comment: Good answer. I would also recommend showing OP that you can turn just about anything into a string by doing `str(thing)`. It's a bit more efficient than using `str.format`

Answer (score 0):

I think this is clearer

```
return "The sum of %s is %s." % (list2,  add_list(list1))
```

Comment: But why is the code showing error even if I modified the elements in the list to strings...

Comment: I dont undesrtand, your code works for me if you modify the return line with the line I wrote: In [22]: summarize([1,2,3])
Out[22]: 'The sum of [1, 2, 3] is 6.'

Comment: If you mean why your code doesnt work it's because "".join(list2) this is expecting a list of string, list2 is a list of ints

Comment: If you stil lwant to use your solution then you should do this return "The sum of {} is {}.".format("".join(str(i) for i in list2),    add_list(list1))"

Comment: While this code may solve the problem, a few words of explanation would go a long way to making this answer valuable to future readers.